# Why does webpack not output the filenames in source map?

Tags: javascript, webpack, source-maps

I've tried different `devtool` settings: eval, inline-source-map, eval-source-map, cheap-eval-source-map, cheap-module-eval-source-map. The only one I seemed to be able to produce file names with is the `eval` option.

The eval option produces a sourceURL like the following

```
webpack:///./src/resolvers.js
```

while all other options seems to produce sourceURLs like

```
webpack-internal:///1
```

I'm aiming to use the `cheap-module-eval-source-map` option.

This is the webpack config

```
var path = require("path")
var nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals")

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  target: "node",
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.gql$/,
        use: "raw-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      GQLSchema$: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/schema/types.gql"),
      Utils: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/utils")
    }
  },
  watch: true,
  devtool: "cheap-module-eval-source-map"
}
```

[Here is the entire project](https://github.com/krokofant/numbersapi-graphql-server/tree/9235a7bee63e300955f7a15d96717c02b110dd90)